# Outlook 2016 Add-in not working

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-2016

I am working on an Outlook add in and it works fine for all the browsers.  However it does not work with Outlook 2016.  Initially it worked with Mac, but now it doesn't seem to work with either.  It seems like the `Office.initialize` is never called?

I've searched and tried things for hours but nothing works.  Comparing my manifest and initialization to others, I seem to have essentially the same code.

I used the yeoman generator and I am using Office UI Fabric React as my framework.  Really at a loss at this point, wondering if anyone has any suggestions or a way to see if any errors are thrown in the Outlook Desktop app?

**Update** 
After much searching and trying things, and starting from scratch, it seems that the add-in stops working as soon as I start using the Office-JS API.  Specifically I'm getting the `userProfile` and the to, from, cc fields from the email `Office.context.mailbox.item`.

Still unable to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

When using Office-JS APIs, be sure to call those APIs only after Office.initialize has been called.

Beyond that, there are a few options for debugging add-ins in Outlook 2016. [The last section on this page](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/get-started/create-and-debug-office-add-ins-in-visual-studio) describes how to attach the Visual Studio debugger to the process running the add-in. Be sure to enable Script Debugging in IE options.

There also are a couple of newer options for debugging Office add-ins:

- [Launch the Visual Studio debugger from a task pane](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/testing/attach-debugger-from-task-pane) (in Outlook, I right-clicked on the task pane to see this option)
- [On Windows 10, debug using F12 tools](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/testing/debug-add-ins-using-f12-developer-tools-on-windows-10) (simple to use, and doesn't require Visual Studio)

For an Outlook add-in running in OWA, just open F12 Developer Tools in any web browser.

Comment: Yes, the code for Office-JS APIs is within the `Office.initialize` and even within a `document.ready` inside the Office.initialize.  I'll see about downloading Visual Studio (I've been using Visual Studio Code) so I can debug with Outlook 2016...